# How to add custom field to menu admin backend page (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Hi I'm trying to create custom field in the menu admin page in wordpress.
I find that ACF doing it,
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-menus/

But I don't want to do it with plugin.

Thanks

Comment: how many custom field you want to add?

Comment: start with two fields

Comment: add custom_meta_box for doing that